# How to get Max value same length array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

My array is below

```
int[] T1 = new int[]{1,5,4};
int[] T2 = new int[]{2,4,3};
int[] T3 = new int[]{7,9,1};
```

A result of the sequence I want it is as follows .

```
int[] result = {7,9,4}
```

I want to look for a max value same index[(e.g) 1,2,7) in array.

and Merging array is `int[] result = {7,9,4}`

please let me know best way

thanks

Comment: Can you concretise your question?

Comment: I think using for loop would be the best approach here, like: `for(i=0 to arraylength) { compare elements on position i, add to array biggest element }`

Comment: @wudzik can you show example source to me?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan sure. which part does not understand my question?

Comment: is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gSREa5) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple method for performing your desired operation.

```
int[] result = new int[T1.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < T1.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = new[] {T1[i], T2[i], T3[i]}.Max();
}
```

You'll have to add `using System.Linq` in order to enable the `Max()` extension.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a method that allows you to use any number of arrays:

```
static T[] MaxElements<T>(params T[][] arrays) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, arrays[0].Length)
                     .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, arrays.Length)
                                            .Select(a => arrays[a][i]).Max()).ToArray();
}
```

You'll have to add the `using System.Linq;` for this one too. You'll have to make sure that all the elements passed in have the same lengths else you will run into an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
It can be used as follows;

```
var result = MaxElements(T1, T2, T3);
```

Comment: This is limited to 3 arrays.

Comment: @MohammadMirMostafa: See the update. It allows you to use any number of arrays.

Comment: Yes. It's better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetMaxArray(new[] { 1, 5, 4 }, new[] { 2, 4, 3 }, new[] { 7, 9, 1 });
    }
    private static void GetMaxArray(params int[][] m)
    {
        var length = m.First().Length;
        var r = new int[length];
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            r[i] = m.Select(a => a[i]).Max();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] GetMaxValueArray(List<int[]> arrayList)
{
        int[] result = null;
        int maxArraySize;
        int maxCurrentArrayItemValue;

        if (arrayList != null && arrayList.Count > 0)
        {
            maxArraySize = 0;

            foreach (int[] array in arrayList)
                if (array.Length > maxArraySize)
                    maxArraySize = array.Length;

            result = new int[maxArraySize];

            for (int i = 0; i < maxArraySize; i++)
            {
                maxCurrentArrayItemValue = 0;

                foreach (int[] array in arrayList)
                    if (i < array.Length)
                        if (array[i] > maxCurrentArrayItemValue)
                            maxCurrentArrayItemValue = array[i];

                result[i] = maxCurrentArrayItemValue;
            }
        }

        return result;
 }
```